# Joomla not showing articles

Tags: css, templates, joomla, joomla-article

For reference, [This](http://i256.photobucket.com/albums/hh179/mechaFrieza/scr2.png) is what the site looks like,

[here](http://pastebin.com/JenwJYvG) is the index.php
and

[here](http://pastebin.com/AQkPr34A) is the current template.css being used.

My problems are as follow:

1. Using the first menu, [Quem Somos] as example, I've created a category and under it I've put some articles. Using the default `mod_mainmenu`, how would I make it display a dropdown menu?

   I can't do it even if the primary menu items are created as lists of categories or, when the submenus are linked directly to articles and then these submenus are linked to a primary menu, the module just shows that one level pill menu shown. Do i need an extra module or something? am meddling with swmenufree but am guessing something basic as a dropdown menu fed by a category/section is something that should be built in.
2. In my quest for a 3 column template I've most definitively destroyed something and now whenever i click any link (all links have articles to back them up) the site just shows the same main page. clicking and typing (c&p actually) the entire URL in the address bar gets me nowhere also. The URL it shows is correct but what i keep seeing is the landing page

Comment: for point 2. it maybe that if you have a different template for the homepage it's set to show on all pages. go into the menus and look at the bottom of the page to see where articles are assigned. (everything but home should be set).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're missing the following:

```
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Place this where you want your content to appear (your middle column)